# How to center div apparently inside canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I'm making a snake game with JavaScript and I'm trying to add the 'pause menu' feature. I manage to make the menu appear when the user clicks the pause icon, but I wish I could make the menu appear centered inside the canvas where the game is rendered. This is what I got:

[image]

How can I make it look like it is centered inside the canvas? **I know I can accomplish that by setting the margin-left, margin-right, etc to a certain number**, but that doesn't work well in my case because my website is supposed to be responsive to window resize. I want that menu to maintain almost the same dimensions whatever is the width of the window. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="body-divs">
    <div id="score-div">
        <span id="score-text"></span>
        <span id="level-text"></span>
        <button id="pause-button"><i id="pause-resume-icon" class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="pause-menu">
        <span class="menu-text"> Paused </span>
        <div id="game-menu-div-4">
            <button class="game-menu-button" id="resume-button"> Resume </button>
            <button class="game-menu-button" id="back-button"> Main Menu </button>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <canvas class="body-divs" id="stage" width="600" height="600">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.body-divs, #score-div{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#pause-menu {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Manaspace';
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gold;
    border-radius: 4px 4px;
}

#resume-button, #back-button {
    margin: 10px;
}

#resume-button {
    font-size: 22px;
}

#back-button {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `#pause-menu` and the `canvas` in shared `.container` parent who has `position: relative` and then center the `#pause-menu` using `position: absolute` along with `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to center it over the `canvas`. Example:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

#pause-menu {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Manaspace';
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: gold;
    border-radius: 4px 4px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#resume-button, #back-button {
    margin: 10px;
}

#resume-button {
    font-size: 22px;
}

#back-button {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="score-div">
  <span id="score-text"></span>
  <span id="level-text"></span>
  <button id="pause-button">pause</button>
</div>  

<div class="container">
  <div id="pause-menu">
    <span class="menu-text"> Paused </span>
    <div id="game-menu-div-4">
      <button class="game-menu-button" id="resume-button"> Resume </button>
      <button class="game-menu-button" id="back-button"> Main Menu </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <canvas class="body-divs" id="stage" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#pause-menu {
position: relative;
```

An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.

Comment: In fact, that works to center the div. But if you look closely to the HTML, you will note that the pause menu e between the score div and the canvas. In that way, when I set position to relative they appear in that exact order: score div first, pause menu then and canvas after.I tried lots of 'position' value and the only one that made de menu seem to overlap the canvas  was absolute...